# Regex Regular Expression 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm tinkering with Regex and I'm trying to edit a string so that it will do the following...

**Original text**

```
Mr. Bob had 1.3 pounds, he didn't have much. Did he care? Joe Bloggs, Esq. thinks he does. However, he paused... But, what will you do with the .7?
```

**Actual Outcome**

```
Mr. 
Bob had 1.3 pounds, he didn't have much. 
Did he care? 
Joe Bloggs, Esq. thinks he does. 
However, he paused... But, what will you do with the .7?
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
Mr. Bob had 1.3 pounds, he didn't have much.
Did he care?
Joe Bloggs, Esq. thinks he does.
However, he paused...
But, what will you do with the .7?
```

so far my statement is..

```
print re.sub(r'(?<!..\.|.Mr|Esq|Mrs|.Ms)[.?]\s+', '\\g<0>\n', s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate out the Negative look-behinds to overcome the fixed-width pattern requirement like this -

```
r'(?<!Mr)(?<!Mrs)(?<!Ms)(?<!Esq)(?<!e.g)(?<!i.e)[.?]\s+'
```

This works -

```
>>> print re.sub(r'(?<!Mr)(?<!Mrs)(?<!Ms)(?<!Esq)(?<!e.g)(?<!i.e)[.?]\s+', '\\g<0>\n', s)
Mr. Bob had 1.3 pounds, he didn't have much. 
Did he care? 
Joe Bloggs, Esq. thinks he does. 
However, he paused... 
But, what will you do with the .7?

>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I altered the statement a little to work with the file and it works like a charm. I forgot to include a i.e. or e.g. in my example sorry! Is it possible to include those within the statemeny? "i.e. he is okay" or "e.g. he is okay"

Comment: @user3423572 Whatever values you don't want to split, just add everything except the final dot(.) within the (?<term)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex has `.Mr`, which requires `Mr` to be preceded by another character.  But your `Mr` appears at the beginning of the string, so there's no character before it.

I don't see any obvious way around this using the builtin `re` module.  It requires lookbehinds to have a fixed length, so there's no way to have one lookbehind for both `Esq` and `Mr`-not-preceded-by-anything.  However, the `regex` library doesn't have this limitation, so you could do it with that library, using a simpler regex to boot:

```
>>> print regex.sub(r'(?<!\.|Mr|Esq|Mrs|Ms)[.?]\s+', '\\g<0>\n', s)
Mr. Bob had 1.3 pounds, he didn't have much. 
Did he care? 
Joe Bloggs, Esq. thinks he does. 
However, he paused... But, what will you do with the .7?
```

(Edit: Other answers have now shown that it can be done with `re` by using separate lookbehinds.  Still might be worth looking at `regex`, though, it has some useful differences from `re.)

Comment: Though I failed to install it through `pip`, but you are right. nice info.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed your negative lookbehind from the regex. It works for the provided input. Not sure how it will react for your others.

```
print re.sub(r'(?<!Mr)(?<!Esq)(?<!Mrs)(?<!Ms)[.?!]\s+', '\\g<0>\n', s)
```